# How can we add sections, sub, subsub nonumbers in \usetheme{Antibes}?

Tags: beamer, themes

How can we add sections, sub, subsub nonumbers in `\usetheme{Antibes}`?

As we know, in `\usetheme{Antibes}`, the sections, subsections, subsubsections are listed by their name.

How can we add the section numbers, secction title/ subsection nonumbers /  subsubsection nonumbers subsubsecction title insted of just their titles.

An example is:

We do not want

```
Introduction
  history
    good
```

But want

```
1. Introduction
  1.1 history
    1.1.1 good
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes} 

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
        \hskip6pt \thesection\ \insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}%
        \hskip12pt \thesection.\thesubsection\ \insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{subsubsection in head/foot}%
        \hskip18pt \thesection.\thesubsection.\thesubsubsection\ \insertsubsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\title{test}

\begin{document}
\section{blub}
\subsection{Propiedades Elctricas}
\subsubsection{Anlisis de Impedancia}
\begin{frame}{frametitle}{framesubtitle}
Hola
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sure. Just put all the `\thesection.\thesubsection.\thesubsubsection\ \insertsubsubsectionhead` etc. in one line.

Comment: Thankyou. then how can I let the font being larger?

Comment: @xldd by setting the appropriate template, for example `\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\large}`